# Cant View CheckBoxList from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have 2 pages , one to add data to database , and the other to edit it, so in the add I have a CheckBoxList , I added them as follow in the database

URLS : 1,2,3,4,5
and the numbers are the values "keys" from the checkbox

I used this code

```
String values = "";        
foreach (ListItem i in CheckBoxList1.Items)
{
      if (CheckBoxList1.Items.Count == 1)
             values += i.Value;
      else
        if (i.Selected)
        {
             values += i.Value + ",";

        }
}
```

and then I added the values to the database , and it worked perfect ,
 now my problem is in the edit page ,as first I want to show the checked boxes from the database , I used this but its not working

in the page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
          ... connection to the database .. etc

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (rd.Read())
                {                 
                    String values = rd["urls"].ToString();//workes perfect

                    string[] arr = values.Split(',');//works perfect
                    int x = CheckBoxList1.Items.Count;//this will get me a zero

                    foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)// doesnt enter here
                    {
                        foreach (string s in arr)
                        {
                            if (item.Text == s)
                            {
                                item.Selected = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

             .... //exceptions handling
```

my code for the aspx page

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="urls_ds" 
                        DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id">
   </asp:CheckBoxList>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="urls_ds" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testing_cs %>" 
       SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_urls]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I am getting the checkboxlist from the database using SqlDataSource , and in the page I can see them put as I print the count of the items its zero

where could be the problem ??

Thanks

Comment: The problem appears to be that `CheckBoxList1` is *empty* (as per the fact that its Count property returns 0). Where are its values supposed to come from? Please post its definition on that page.

Comment: thanks for the reply , as I said , i am getting the data from the database using SqlDataSource and I can see them in the page

Comment: The code you've posted is for the edit page's Load event, correct? Where is the code that puts items into `CheckBox1`? Because that seems to be where the issue lies.

Comment: I updated the question , please check it , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit : This post describes your problem exactly http://forums.asp.net/t/1488957.aspx/1, and offers two solutions

Here is what I see

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
```

This means you are on a NEW copy of the page, so CheckBoxList1 is empty until you load it with data. which I bet happens further down in your code.  Just make sure you load it before you use it.

Edit : When using a SqlDataSource to populate controls, you must remember that controls referencing it bind AFTER Page_Load execution.  The link above gives two work around methods (either manually calling Control.DataBind or handling the Control.Databound event).

Comment: I am loading the data using SqlDataSource , where should I load them in the code , if I want to do it ?

Comment: Page_Load occurs before SqlDataSource does its Update, so the data isn't there.

Comment: thanks for your answer , could you see my code for the aspx ?
thanks

Comment: Check out this post [http://forums.asp.net/t/1488957.aspx/1](http://forums.asp.net/t/1488957.aspx/1)

Comment: thanks a lot , it worked 
I used this    `DropDownList1.DataBind();` in the page load